# WinForm Hosted in WPF Mouse.getPosition not working

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, mouse, elementhost

I have some element (ZedGraph) hosted in a wpf Window.
I want to get the x and the y coordinate of my mousecursor.
It works on the rest of the window but as soon as I hover over the Elementhost the numbers are frozen.
I already found out that Elementhost does not pass the events, but I dont found a working solution to that Problem.

many thanks in advance for any hints on that problem

Comment: Welcome to SO Andre. Don't be shy and share the code you are using to get the position at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the MouseMove Event for your **Page window**. Let e.g the name of the
Page window be mainWindow, and the Element's name be myElement1. Then you can get
the position X-Y of your element and use it in comparisons with Mouse positions X-Y, like in the following example,

```
private void mainWindow_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Point thepnt = new System.Windows.Point();

    thepnt = e.GetPosition(myElement1);
    if (((thepnt.X<=100)|| (thepnt.X > myElement1.Width)) || (thepnt.Y < 100))
    {
       //do something...
    }
    else
    {
       //do something else....
    }
}
```

Hope these help.